Prove $z^{ca}-z^{-cb}-c(z^a-z^{-b})\ge 0$ for $z\in[0,1]$, $c\in[0,1]$, $1<a<b$.
Let $c\in[0,1]$, and $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ with $1<a<b$.
Let $f:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be defined by:
$$f(z)=z^{ca}-z^{-cb}-c(z^a-z^{-b})$$
for $z\in[0,1]$.
I would like to prove $f(z)\ge 0$ for all $z\in[0,1]$.
As $z\rightarrow 0$, the $z^{-b}$ term dominates, so $f(z)\rightarrow+\infty$.
And taking a second order approximation around $z=1$ we have:
$$f(z)=\frac{c}{2}(1-c)(b-a)(a+b) (z-1)^2 + O((z-1)^3)$$
as $z\rightarrow 1$.
$\frac{c}{2}(1-c)(b-a)(a+b) (z-1)^2\ge 0$ for all $z$, so this is promising at least.
Is there some standard inequality from which my desired result follows trivially?

The non-trivial case is that $0 < c \le 1$ and $0 < z < 1$. Let
$$f(c) := \frac{z^{ca} - z^{-cb}}{c} - (z^a - z^{-b}).$$
We have
\begin{align*}
 c^2f'(c) &= (caz^{ca} + cbz^{-cb})\ln z - z^{ca} + z^{-cb}\\
 &= (caz^{ca} + cbz^{-cb})\cdot \frac{\ln (z^{ca} z^{cb})}{ca + cb} - z^{ca} + z^{-cb}\\
 &= \frac{az^{ca} + bz^{-cb}}{a + b}\cdot \ln (z^{ca} z^{cb}) - z^{ca} + z^{-cb}\\
 &\le \frac{az^{ca} + az^{-cb}}{a + a}\cdot \ln (z^{ca} z^{cb}) - z^{ca} + z^{-cb}\tag{1}\\
 &= \frac{z^{ca} + z^{-cb}}{2}\cdot \ln (z^{ca} z^{cb}) - z^{ca} + z^{-cb}\\
 &\le \frac{z^{ca} + z^{-cb}}{2}\cdot \frac{2(z^{ca}z^{cb} - 1)}{z^{ca}z^{cb}+1}- z^{ca} + z^{-cb}\tag{2}\\
 &= 0
\end{align*}
where in (1) we use $\frac{az^{ca} + az^{-cb}}{a + a} - \frac{az^{ca} + bz^{-cb}}{a + b} = \frac{(z^{ca} - z^{-cb})(b-a)}{2(a + b)} \le 0$, and in (2) we use
$\ln u \le \frac{2(u-1)}{u+1}$ for all $0 < u \le 1$.
Thus, we have $f'(c) \le 0$. Also, $f(1) = 0$. Thus, $f(c) \ge 0$ on $0 < c \le 1$. We are done.

That proof is harder than I expected! I feel better about my failure to get it myself! Thanks!

@cfp Perhaps there is simpler proof. Also, since it is the form of $x^c - y^c \ge c(x - y)$, perhaps it is not new.
